# tezos node v9.1 getting lots of HTTP 404

Tags: node

Running a local node to query blocks/transactions.  It is running in archive mode and it up to tip. Since upgrading to 9.1 we get frequent HTTP 404 errors calling something simple like
/chains/main/blocks/{height}/header where height is a valid block number perhaps a few minutes old.